# nginx error 500 with slash in rewrite mechanism (import from apache)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I have got this config file without any rewrite

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/testhop.com/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name testhop.com;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I have found some code for making rewriting:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

I have modified it to final form of:

```
server {
(...)

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/$uri&$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
(...)
}
```

But this configuration gives me the 500 error.
My original apache rewrite is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

How make it works in format index.php/url-params
?

Answer (score 0):

Your `location ~ \.php$` block accepts URIs that end with `.php` (not including the query string). By adding a `/` after the `.php` you are appending *path info*.

Using [the documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) this should work for you:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
}
```

The `location` regex has been changed to accept URIs with path info. The `try_files` directive has been replaced by an [evil if](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), as the URI needs to be split first, before being tested for file existence.

I like to place the `include` statement before any `fastcgi_param` statement to avoid the latter being silently overridden.